# Where to create QOpenGLDebugLogger in a qml application?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtopengl, openglcontext

I have a Qt6 qml application, and plan to add several QQuickFramebufferObject descendant components to use OpenGL directly.

I need OpenGL logs, and I learned that I can use QOpenGLDebugLogger for this. As a PoC, I can create the QOpenGLDebugLogger object in my QQuickFramebufferObject's createRenderer() method.

My goal is to have a single QOpenGLDebugLogger object for my whole application that logs messages from the qml's opengl context, but in my main() there is (understandably) no opengl context yet:

```
warning default: QOpenGLDebugLogger::initialize(): no current OpenGL context found.
```

Is it reasonable what I want to achieve? Or it is nonsense, and separate context (from the rest of the qml application) is created by Qt that is only belongs to a given QQuickFramebufferObject?